# Vector function derivatives for discrete adjoint equation

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus

I'm in the process of deriving a discrete [adjoint equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_equation).

I'm trying to find the derivative of the vector $\textbf{X}_{1}$ with respect to the vector $\textbf{X}_0$ but I am not able to,

$\textbf{X}_{1}=\big (\mathbb{E}(\textbf{X}_0) \big) ^{-1}\,\mathbb{F}\textbf{X}_0$

with $\mathbb{F}$ a constant square matrix and $\mathbb{E}$ a invertible square matrix such that,

$\mathbb{E}(\textbf{X}_0)=\mathbb{I}_q^T \bigg ( diag(\mathbb{I}_q \,\textbf{X}_0) \,\mathbb{D}_x^q\bigg ).$

$\mathbb{I}_q$ and $\mathbb{D}_x^q$ are rectangular constant matrices. $diag(\textbf{Y})$ is the diagonal matrix having as diagonal entries the elements of $\textbf{Y}$.

I know that, for any vector $\textbf{Y}$,

$\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}(\textbf{Y})\textbf{X}_0}{\partial \textbf{Y}}=\mathbb{I}_q^T \bigg ( diag(\mathbb{D}_x^q\,\textbf{X}_0) \,\mathbb{I}_q\bigg )$

and,

$\frac{\partial \big (\mathbb{E}(\textbf{Y}) \big) ^{-1}\,\mathbb{F}\textbf{X}_0}{\partial \textbf{X}_0}=\big (\mathbb{E}(\textbf{Y}) \big) ^{-1}\,\mathbb{F}.$

Where should I go from here to get $\frac{\partial \textbf{X}_{1}}{\partial \textbf{X}_{0}}$

Comment: I believe that $$\frac{\partial \textbf{X}_1}{\partial \textbf{X}_0} = \mathbb{E}^{-1}\Big(\mathbb{F}-\mathbb{I}_q^T{\rm diag}(\mathbb{D}_x^q\mathbb{E}^{-1}\mathbb{F}\textbf{X}_0)\mathbb{I}_q\Big)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's replace your elaborate variables with something easier to type
$$\eqalign{
 x &= \mathbf{X}_0 &,\,\,y &= \mathbf{X}_1 \cr
 E &= \mathbb{E}(\mathbf{X}_0) &,\,\,F &= \mathbb{F} \cr
 J &= \mathbb{I}_q &,\,\,K &= \mathbb{D}^q_x \cr
}$$
Now your basic equation can be expressed as
$$Ey = Fx$$
Taking derivatives (with respect to $x$) yields
$$\eqalign{
dE\,y + E\,dy &= F\,dx \cr
J^T{\rm diag}(Ky)J+E\,dy &= F\,I \cr
E\,dy &= F - J^T{\rm diag}(Ky)J \cr
 dy &= E^{-1}\Big(F - J^T{\rm diag}(Ky)J\Big) \cr
 dy &= E^{-1}\Big(F - J^T{\rm diag}(KE^{-1}Fx)J\Big) \cr
}$$
Reverting to your variables, yields the result in my previous comment.

Comment: I checked your answer using with small randomly generated matrices and finite-difference, it works great.